# Increase integer variable by one on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to increase the value for the globally defined variable highestPurposeValue in case the if condition is true, but it does not work. It returns every time 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
var highestPurposeValue = 0;

$('#addJobPurposeButton').on('click', function(){

    var value = $('#jobPurposeInputForm').val();


    $('#jobPurposeList li').map(function () {

        var item = $(this).find("input[name^='jobPurpose']").attr('name');

        var itemNumber = item.match(/\d+/); // returns an array.

        if (itemNumber[0] > highestPurposeValue) {

            var num = parseInt(itemNumber[0]);

            var plusOne = num+1;

            highestPurposeValue = plusOne;

        }

    });
```

Comment: I can see many reasons as to why this may go wrong. Could you provide your HTML along as well ?

Comment: If the `item.match(/\d+/);` returns an array of `string`'s (can hold number characters though), your `if (itemNumber[0] > highestPurposeValue)` will never evaluate properly as the variables are of two different types.

Comment: `$(this).find("input[name^='jobPurpose']").attr('name')` would return 'jobPurpose' and then it would look like `jobPurpose.match(/\d+/)` so you are looking for numbers in a string that don't contain any?

Comment: Use **parseFloat** `if (parseFloat(itemNumber[0]) > highestPurposeValue) {`

Comment: I use `parseFloat(itemNumber[0])` in the if condition and `parseInt(itemNumber[0])` with `parseFloat(itemNumber[0])`, but the variable `highestPurposeValue` increase just one time :-(